# configure intellisense to load jsdoc

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

Currently intellisense only load javascript comments in xml way [1]:

```
      function getArea(radius)
      {
      /// <summary>Determines the area of a circle that has the specified radius parameter.</summary>
      /// <param name="radius" type="Number">The radius of the circle. </param>
      /// <returns type="Number">The area.</returns>

      var areaVal;
      areaVal = Math.PI * radius * radius;
      return areaVal;
  }
```

Is possible configure to can load a common jsdoc[?

As example:

```
  /** 
   * Determines the area of a circle that has the specified radius parameter.
   * @param Number radius The radius of the circle.
   * @return Number The area.
   */
    function getArea(radius) {
         var areaVal = Math.PI * radius * radius;
          return areaVal;
    }
```

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138.aspx

Comment: The docs don't mention this as being supported, I'm afraid